# How to remove class using javascript

Tags: jquery

I have `class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-active ui-btn-up-c"` for anchor tag and from this class I have to remove the `ui-btn-active` on button `click` function.how can i remove this.using jquery.

thanks.

Comment: you can do that by jQuery : `$(...).removeClass('classname');`  Ref : http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: I done by this way but not working.

Comment: write what you had done.. Explain more...

Comment: -1. Tagged jquery, [type question in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+remove+class+using+jquery) -> [first result](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). Even without using jquery this is an oft-repeated question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
 element.className = element.className.split(' ').filter(function(v) {
     return v!='theclassiwanttoremove'
 }).join(' ');
```

To be compatible with IE8, you might want to [add a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

---

EDIT : I now see the jQuery tag... This answer is now useless in that case.

Comment: where i write this above code.I mean on button click or what?

Comment: @user2000423 See Dipesh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('a').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
});
```

Comment: @dystroy please see question carefully you will see jQuery tag...please read it before commenting.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my comment : I mean your answer is valid, that's just the question that is just too trivial.

Comment: @dystroy ohhh i see...let me roll back....sorry Mate

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByID("IDNAME").className="";
```

where IDNAME = ID attribute of element